# Best Practice for returning multiple objects/dtos in RestController

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, view, dto

While looking at tons of articles about Rest APIs in Spring Boot, I've noticed that most of them use just one type of object per method in their controllers. So it will be something like this:

```html
@GetMapping("/posts")
    public ResponseEntity<List<PostDto>> readPosts() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(
                someService.getAll()
        );
}
```

However, in real-life scenarios, we need to pass multiple objects/lists of different types that provide the information the client needs. My question is simple; how does one achieve that in Restful services?

Comment: Lets say you want to return 3 DTO's (A,B,C) in your ResponseEntity. Create a DTO D that accepts 3 DTOs (A,B,C) as its attribute. Then return D in the ResponseEntity.

Comment: The endpoint should be defined based on resources So if resources changes which mean you have some issues in defining endpoints

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom DTO contain multiple objects/lists of different types, set properties after retrieve your data from service and return the custom DTO

Answer (score 0):

Returning a List directly is not recommended as it is can bind you to a particular collection to return.

**Return an object**: ReadPostResponse which can contain objects, lists as suggested above.
This allows you to extend the Response as per your need. But try to maintain a contract with client about ResponseType returned.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any java mapper (MapStruct, ModelMapper,...) to map your entity to DTO and return DTOs after mapping.

[MapStruct Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMkr7X9JBPp4fc02yWxKsbYdLyBeiO4wt)

```
        @GetMapping("/posts")
        public ResponseEntity<?> readPosts() {
           List<PostDto> dtos = someMapper.map(someService.getAll());  
          return ResponseEntity.ok(dtos);
        }
```

}